# Default Style Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-button, android-jetpack-compose

Does somebody know how to change default style to button?
Style in xml:

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
```

And I want to convert it to Jetpack Compose.

In default compose sample(Android Studio Canary) You can see ui.theme folder and it's a analog of values folder but without Strings and Dimens. So how I can add Strings and Dimens to this compose folder?

Comment: "And I want to convert it to Jetpack Compose" -- the details will depend on what is in `ButtonStyle`. "So how I can add Strings and Dimens to this compose folder?" -- `stringResource()` and `dimensionResource()` let you reference string and dimension resources, respectively, though I think they are only available inside of a composable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the `Button` source, you'll notice that it uses a couple of default values that you can customize (via params or via custom style).

- `shape`: Uses `MaterialTheme.shapes.small` (you can customized this field in your style);

```kotlin
val shapes = Shapes(
    small = CutCornerShape(4.dp), // << here
    medium = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    large = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
)
```

- `colors`: which is an instance of `ButtonColors` that provides `backgroundColor`,  `contentColor`, `disabledBackgroundColor` and `disabledContentColor`. Look into the `Button.buttonColors` function to see how to customize the colors for your button.
- In terms of text, the `Button` component gets the text style from `MaterialTheme.typography.button`, so you can override this field in your style to customize your button's text.

```kotlin
val typography = Typography(
    ...
    button = defaultTypography.button.copy(
        fontFamily = yourFontFamily, 
        color = Color.Yellow
    )
)
```

For text and dimensions you can continue using XML files (res/values) and refer to them using `stringResource(id)` and `dimensionResource(id)` functions respectively.

Comment: "For text and dimensions you can continue using XML files (res/values)". Or, I can create enum classes with Dp(or Sp) and String

Comment: I still prefer to use XML mainly for strings because it makes easier the app's internationalization.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [nglauber answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733385/2016562) you can customize the shape, typography and color in your theme, or in the Button parameters.

Also you can override these values and build a default button style.
Something like:

```
@Composable
fun DefaultButtonStyle(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        //override the shape
        shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(small = CutCornerShape(12.dp)),
        //Override the typography.button using the merge method
        typography = MaterialTheme.typography.copy(
            button = MaterialTheme.typography.button.merge(TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp))),
        //override the colors define in the material theme
        colors = MaterialTheme.colors.copy(
            primary = Color.Yellow,
            onPrimary = Color.Blue)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Then just use it with:

```
DefaultButtonStyle() {
    Button(onClick = { /*....*/ }) {
        Text(text = "BUTTON")
    }
}
```